# Heavyside Lorentz units and Gaussian units

Tags: electromagnetism, units, unit-conversion

What is the relation between [Heavyside Lorentz units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units) and [Gaussian units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units)?

From [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units), I noticed there are $4\pi$ difference between them, but my TA wants more.

Is there other relation or important property for each unit system?

Comment: What kind of TA tortures their students with units?

Comment: Anyway, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units#Maxwell.27s_equations) seems to confirm that Heaviside-Lorentz is halfway between Gaussian and SI. As a rule of thumb: put the $4\pi$ where you'd put them in SI units but replace the $\varepsilon$ and $\mu$ by $c$ just as in Gaussian units.